# Hidden words in sentences

Tags: word, english

There is one word hidden in each of these sentences, what are they related to?

1. I held the food to my lips.
2. The den in the jungle lives the lion.
3. High-quality biscuits are frequently requested.
4. Most of the cars in the nation are old.
5. Parents or kids are allowed to enter this place.
6. The water level is low, thus leading to shortage of water.
7. Chry sent the parcel to her mum.

Clue

> Flowers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well...

> I held the food **to** my **lips**. (tulips)

> The **den** in **the** jungle lives the **lion**. (dandelion)

> **High**-quality **biscuits** are frequently requested. (hibiscus)

> Most of the **car**s in this **nation** are old. (carnation)

> Parents **or kids** are allowed to enter this place. (orchids)

> The water level is **low**, **thus** leading to a water shortage. (lotus)

> **Chry sent the** parcel to her **mum**. (chrysanthemum)